# Finding the XCode SVN Version Number

Tags: xcode, svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows, and XCode on Mac OSX to commit to an SVN repo.

Machine setup is:

- Tortoise 1.7.13/Subversion 1.7.10 on Windows 7
- XCode 7.3 on OSX 10.11.4

I want to update the version of TortoiseSVN that I am using, but I don't want to fall into the trap of updating to a version of Subversion that XCode doesn't support yet.

**How can I check which version of SVN my XCode install is using?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the SVN version for your system type the following in to terminal:

```
     svn --version
```

You should see a line at the top of the output stating `svn, version 1.7.20 (r1667490)` or similar which will indicate the version number

You can upgrade SVN on your system as long as you have `Xcode Command Line Tools` installed.

If you have this installed you will need to download the SVN source using the following command:

```
    cd ~/Downloads/
    curl -o subversion-latest.tar.gz http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/subversion/subversion-1.7.8.tar.gz
    tar -xvf subversion-latest.tar.gz
```

And to install use the following:

```
    cd ~/Downloads/subversion-1.7.*
    sh get-deps.sh neon
    cd neon/
    ./configure --with-ssl
    make
    sudo make install
    cd ..
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-neon
    make
    sudo make install
```

This will compile the downloaded source for SVN on your system and install it.